# Cosa significa "un certo qual"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, adjectives

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te*, di Paola Mastrocola, ho letto:

> Solo il padre, il saggio e coltissimo notaio Gualtiero Cantirami, sembrava possedere *un certo qual* saldo equilibrio, e con fare sornione soleva dire: «Non importa, è una femmina, troverà marito».

Cercando su Internet, ho trovato altre costruzioni con "un certo qual". Ad esempio:

- In un certo qual modo
- In un certo qual senso
- Per un certo qual carattere ignobile che vi domina

Tuttavia, non riesco a capire qual è la funzione o il significato dell'espressione "un certo qual" nelle frasi precedenti. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: Come nell'inglese "to some extent" o "in some way".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Un certo qual* viene utilizzato per aggiungere un senso di vaghezza al nome che segue. Ad esempio si veda nel [dizionario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/quale/) (significato 5b)

> *un certo qual* (una certa qual) serve (come *non so quale*, di cui al n. *1 b*) a dare alla frase un senso di indeterminatezza: *sentiva dentro di sé una certa qual voglia di vendicarsi*. V. inoltre i pron. qualche, qualsia, qualsisia, qualsivoglia, e gli avv. qualora e qualvolta.

Nell'esempio *sentiva dentro di sé una certa qual voglia di vendicarsi*, la locuzione *un certo qual* indica che la voglia di vendicarsi non è precisa e definita (*voglio strozzarlo!*) ma al contrario un generico desiderio di pareggiare i conti.

Comment: È curioso come *certo*, in questo contesto, abbia il significato esattamente opposto a quello etimologico e che tuttora ha in altri contesti. Sarebbe interessante indagare su come ci si sia arrivati.

Comment: @egreg Questo secondo significato è presente anche in latino (e.g. *"certis rebus imperatis regnare jussit”*, *imposte certe condizioni, stabilì di regnare* Cic. Sest. 27,58), per cui credo che sarebbe difficile trovarne l'origine.

Comment: Interessanti osservazioni, entrambe. Denis, sei certo (no pun intended) che l'uso nella frase ciceroniana sia assimilabile a quello di cui stiamo parlando? Dopo tutto, in quel caso le condizioni saranno state ben precise, anche se chi parla non si dilunga a descriverle.

Comment: @DaG Confesso che la frase l'ho presa da Perseus, in cui dà, tra i vari significati di *certus* anche *"sometimes indef., like quidam, and our certain"*. D'altronde la cosa non è sorprendente perché questo significato è passato anche al francese e da lì all'inglese (*certain*, nel senso di alcuni)

Comment: Ottimo, grazie. Magari l'“anello mancante” che cerca @egreg è proprio questo, il passaggio da “certe cose (persone, condizioni)”, ben precise, che so io, ma che ora non descrivo in dettaglio, a “certe cose (persone, condizioni)”, quali che siano, la cui precisa identità non ci interessa.