# Dubbio su diversi usi della parola "certo"

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Ho forse imparato a dire "Certo!". Ieri sera il mio amico di martedì mi ha chiesto "Hai fatto gli arancini?" e io ho risposto "Certo!". Ha sorriso. A cena abbiamo parlato di "Certo che sì", "Certo che no" e anche di "No, certo" e "Certo no". Non ho capito bene... Poi, a metà cena, ha fatto una faccia strana e mi ha detto:

> Si certa che un certo arancino ti fissa. Ora certo mangio quel certo arancino.

Poi l'ha mangiato intero! E mi ha detto di cercare di capire la frase che ho riportato.

Su questo sito ho trovato [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/6306/cosa-significa-un-certo-qual), ma non è uguale e mi confonde di più.

Come devo capire quella frase?

Comment: *“Si certa che un certo arancino ti fissa”*  è una frase sgrammaticata dal significato incerto. Sei sicura che abbia detto questo?

Comment: Potrebbe essere stato "sii" (esortativo); per il resto l'intera frase ha l'aspetto di uno scioglilingua

Comment: Io la trascriverei così: «Sii certa che un certo arancino ti fissa. Ora, (di) certo, mangio quel certo arancino». Certo (!), è una frase un po' forzata, ma corretta.

Comment: @Hachi  E vero! Non era "si" ma "sii", scusate, non ero sicura e pensavo che era giusto "si". Devo cambiare la domanda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forse il motivo per cui ha sorriso alla tua esclamazione risiede nel fatto che la tua pronuncia di "certo" potrebbe essere simpatica e non proprio corretta, o magari lo hai semplicemente detto con molto entusiasmo. Ad ogni modo rispondere "Certo!" corrisponde a "Certamente", ovvero come avrai capito "of course". "Certo che sì" è un modo per affermare qualcosa con ancora più convizione di "Certo" o "Certamente", che si equivalgono. "Certo che no" ha lo stesso uso, ma per negare un'affermazione. "No, certo" è un espressione prettamente verbale, e "certo no" invece non esiste proprio. Ora vediamo la frase enigmatica.

> "Sii certa che un certo arancino ti fissa." (Grazie @Hachi per la correzione di "Si certa" in "Sii Certa")

"Sii certa" = "Stai sicura che" = "Be sure that"

"Un certo arancino" = "Uno degli arancini, non precisato" = "A certain arancino"

> "Be sure that a certain arancino is staring at you."

Per il resto

> "Ora certo mangio quel certo arancino."

"Ora certo" = "For sure now I am gonna..."

"quel certo arancino", qui mi sto riferendo ad un arancino che ho definito in precedenza, come per dire, "prendo un panino a caso, poi metto quel panino scelto casualmente nel frigo". Non c'è un motivo preciso per usare questa forma, e non c'è un cambio di significato rispetto a "prendo un panino, poi lo metto nel frigo", dato che già "un" presume una scelta casuale. È un modo come mille altri per allungare una frase e renderla più divertente, frivola.

> "For sure now I am gonna eat that arancino we were talking about."

Comment: Il “si certa” è un “sii certa” o un “sei certa“?

Comment: Hai ragione, "si certa" è scorretto, dovrebbe essere "sii certa", ora modifico, grazie.

Comment: Grazie, capisco male l'inglese ma ho capito che "certo" nella frase a tre modi diversi. Il mio amico sorrideva perche ama gli arancini, molto se li cucino io. Penso.

Comment: @micina96 You look very incertain (sorry), and when you say "certainly" it must look a little funny, like a contradiction. Especially when you seem to be asking yourself whether you cooked the meal or not, and answering yourself "certainly I did" (might as well be "credo di sî"). That's what I gathered. It's not Italian, it's the way of answering questions.